# sending json content with JQuery, trouble with MIME type and serialization

Tags: jquery, mime-types

I'm trying to POST some json to a web service that accepts json.

The function 'basistech.serializeOptions()' return a Javascript object at the moment, but 
I could easily make is return a string. Note that even though I've set the 'accepts' option,
the header sent is 'Accept: undefined', which leads to some failures on the server side.

Why can't I give a proper mime type in 'accepts'?

```
$.ajax({
            url : basistech.processText_url,
            accepts : "application/json",
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : "json",
            data : basistech.serializeOptions(),
            type : "POST",
            success : function(data) {
               /* whatever */
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#submit-button").busy("hide");
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
POST /r4dws/services/doc/processText HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:15000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1679
Origin: http://localhost:15000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: undefined
Referer: http://localhost:15000/r4dws/demo/xmltextbox.jsp
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=AB76A77DF6906229D281A931D7D10C3C
Request Payload
(messed up)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this....,

```
$.ajax({
            url : basistech.processText_url,
            headers: { 
                     Accept : "application/json",
                     "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            dataType : "json",
            data : basistech.serializeOptions(),
            type : "POST",
            success : function(data) {
               /* whatever */
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#submit-button").busy("hide");
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
```

Comment: It seems to me to be a bug in jquery that you have to do it this way when the documentation would indicate the original way with the `accepts` option should handle it.